# iOS - Can't add calendar event to Gmail calendar with EventKit

Tags: ios, gmail, google-calendar-api, eventkit

I want to add a new calendar event to the default iOS calendar. That works fine, until a user uses Gmail for syncing calendars.

I use the following code:

```
    if (!calendar) {

    calendar = [EKCalendar calendarForEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent eventStore:eventStore];

    // set calendar name
    [calendar setTitle:@"My calendar"];

    EKSource *theSource = [eventStore defaultCalendarForNewEvents].source;
    calendar.source = theSource;

    // save this in NSUserDefaults data for retrieval later
    NSString *calendarIdentifier = [calendar calendarIdentifier];

    NSError *error = nil;
    BOOL saved = [eventStore saveCalendar:calendar commit:YES error:&error];
    if (saved) {
        // saved successfuly, store it's identifier in NSUserDefaults
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:calendarIdentifier forKey:@"railplanner_calendar_identifier"];
    } else {
        // unable to save calendar
        return NO;
    }
}
```

This works fine when iCloud is enabled, or with local calendars.
But when a user uses Gmail for syncing calendars, my custom calendar doesn't appear in the calendars list. The local calendars disappear too.

Does anyone know how I can add a new calendar with a new event to a Gmail (or Google) Calendar?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely to be impossible with the current Google Calendar synchronization, you could detect the type of the default calendar, and in the case of Google use the related Google iPhone API to create your new calendar (not really helpful I know)